# Database table to save attachments

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a databsse for my site, which requires that multiple attachments be uploaded by users in different pages. I wish to keep all those attachments in a single table and reference that table from other tables, where the attachment would be required.

Now the issue is how do I do this? I have not been able to work out the logic of it as yet. What I have in mind is:

```
attachment_tbl:
attach_id  
file_name
description
item1_id -> FK
item2_id -> FK


item1_tbl:
item1_id
attachment1
attachment2


item2_tbl:
item2_id
attachment1
attachment2
attachment3
```

Now how do I save all these attachments in the same table, without having multiple FK in the attachment_tbl, as if I add another item3_tbl, which has attachments, would it mean another FK to be added to the attachments_tbl?

Is there some other simpler and better way to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a relationship table, which connects items and attachments, with a one to many relation:

```
attachment_tbl:
attach_id  
file_name
description

item_tbl:
item_id

item_attachment_tbl:
item_id -> FK
attach_id -> FK
```

For each attachment, there will be a row in the item_attach table:

```
item_id attach_id
-----------------
item1   attach1
item1   attach2
item2   attach3
item3   attach4
item3   attach5
item3   attach6
```

When you want to see the attachments of an item, you must join the tables:

```
select a.file_name, a.description
from attachment_tbl a
inner join item_attachment_tbl ia on a.attach_id = ia.attach_id
where ia.item_id = 87;
```

See also [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f7da/1/0)

Comment: I thought of this, but will it not introduce an added performance hit? Also for multipe "ITEM_TBL", will this also not introduce multiple fields in the "ITEM_ATTACH_TBL"?

Comment: If you have a one to many relationship, that's the way to go. You have to store the connection somewhere and if you have a table for each number of attachments, where will you stop? 10 or 20 tables? See also the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want multiple foreign_keys in attachment_tbl, then you need to have a bridge table at any cost(if you want t keep the relation:) However It will need an extra field as item_tbl_name to distinguish the records for different item tables. Fetching them back is not that much complex.

```
item_attachment_tbl:
item_id -> FK
item_tbl_name
attach_id -> FK
```